# Access to i18n inside Socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, i18next

I use [i18n-2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/i18n-2) for Internationalization like this:

```
    router.get('/route', function (req, res, next) {
      res.redirect('/route/?lang=' + req.i18n.getLocale());
   });
```

Right now, i want to access `req.i18n` inside Socket.io block. i use Socket.io like this:

```
    io.on('connection', function(client){ 
        client.on('event', function(data){
          ...
        });
    });
```

But here, i don't access `req` to use `i18n`. How i can solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [expressBind method](https://github.com/jeresig/i18n-node-2/blob/master/i18n.js#L71-L92) of i18n-2, all it does is attach an `i18n` property to the request object as well as some method proxies for the response object (to use in templates I would assume). You can do the same thing with your client.

```
var I18n = require('i18n-2');
io.on('connection', function(client) {
  client.i18n = new I18n(/* options */);
  client.on('event', function(data) {
    // use client.i18n.__
  });
});
```

You could also get fancier and use [util.inherits](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/util.html) to give the client the same methods that i18n has, but personally I prefer the first way.

Comment: side note: if you want to get the user's default locale, you'll have to pass it back to the server-side socket manually. You can use the [Intl](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl) object to help with this.

Comment: after one day i cant solve this. you know, separation of the express and Socket.io is a huge problem for me. I have a website that works well, and has some functionalities via Socket.io. But i need both of them shares the same request and responses to use functionalities like i18n-2. right now, i set i18n-2 like you say but client.i18.getLocale() gives me default locale not the same one that express has at that time. How i can overcome this? i dont understand you'r side note also.

Comment: you should check out [express-ws](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-ws) or [expressio](http://express-io.org/) if you need full-blown functionality